# how to differentiate form submition on enter keypress and two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have one form with two submit buttons (submit buttons with different IDs). I want to take different actions on :

1. ENTER KEY PRESS
2. Click on submit button # 1
3. Click on submit button # 2

Can  some one guide me, how can I achieve this through jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what actions do you want to take,what code have you tried how are you going to know what the user intends to do based on the enter key ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use such code:

```
$(":input").bind("click keypress", function(evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        alert("ENTER pressed");
    }
    else {
        var sender = evt.target;
        if (sender.type == "submit")
            alert("Submit button " + sender.id + " clicked");
    }
    return true;
});
```

By handling both `click` and `keypress` events you can catch all the desired scenarios.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/PChVY/

Note that pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> also triggers the first submit button `click` event, so to ignore this you can add global flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following ([See Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atKaM/3/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='password']").keypress(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which == 13){
            alert("User pressed 'Enter' in a text input.");
            // do your custom processing here
        }
    });

    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var submitClicked = e.target.id;
        alert("The submit button with id '"+submitClicked+"' was clicked!");

        //probably a switch statement here to do your custom processing based on which submit button was pressed.
    });
});
```

The code above will trap for enter keypress on any text or password input... will ignore enter key presses on `<textarea>` (a desired effect I would think). Pressing enter on any text or password input will NOT trigger the first submit button click.

Just be aware that you'll have to submit your form manually via the code above by using `$([your form selector]).submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){   
    $("input").keypress(function(e){
         if (e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("pressed 'Enter' preventDefault()<br>from Form #"+this.form.id);
            // do your custom processing here
        }
    });
 });
```

works fine for me,