# Disabled a method post action php

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

Hello, I made an autocomplete function when key `enter` is pressed. This part works. But I also have a dynamic `add` button to duplicate this input. The duplicate input uses a form post. BUT now when I press `enter` my page refreshes and I don't want this because my autocomplete doesn't work anymore. Any idea on how I could fix it? Here the code of my input :

```
<td>
    <span id="numpro" >
        <form method="post" action="">

        <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="+" /> 
        <input type="text" id="name" name="add_name"onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, this, 'task');"/>

<?php
    if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
?>

<p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>">
<input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>

<?php
    endwhile;
    }
?>
        </form>
    </span> 
</td>
```

Here is my code for the `enter` key :

```
//------------------COMPLETE CLIENT DESC DIMANCHE----------------------
    function handleEnter(e, obj, field){
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            tempArrayInJS = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
            $("#client1").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);
            $("#desc1").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['proDescription']);
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+obj.value,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    //Enter was pressed, handle it here
```

Here the code of my autocomplete :

```
//------------------AUTO COMPLETE NUMÉRO DE PROJET----------------------    
            $(document).ready(function(){

        //-------AUTO COMPLETE DIMANCHE PROJET-----
                $("#name").autocomplete({
                    source:'getautocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
```

If I forgot to show you some code just tell me. Or if I'm unclear I'll try to explain better . Thanks for help!

Comment: If you remove the form tag, your page won't get submitted, and you could use some jquery to duplicate the data / html for you without submitting the form..

Comment: However you can put `return false;` at the end of your handleEnter function to prevent form submission.

Comment: If I remove form method post action "" my add button wont work. And I try many way for duplicated this ways is the simple I've found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897519/how-to-differentiate-form-submition-on-enter-keypress-and-two-submit-buttons

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146936/allowing-keypress-13-on-login-form-after-specific-div-is-displayed-on-page

Comment: my handle enter work but not my form action this part cause me a refresh .

Comment: here the solution like you say return false   <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">

Comment: That's why you must use `return;` or use `event.preventDefault()` (I've didn't saw that you was using jQuery the first time) to stop the submission (so your refresh).

Comment: Why can't you remove the <form> </form> .. No form, means no submit.. So you can do all your javascript / jquery / ajax.. I don't I understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I write the solution of my problem if you check 3 comment before this one.  <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;"> with this code I've disabled press enter event of my form post and I can do the press enter for my autocomplete. So my question is answer thank to Debflab.

Answer (score 0):

I would inspect browser console to see what kind of requests are going on there, but I assume that with enter browser is submitting also the form that is around your html:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
```

Try to put `e.preventDefault()` to not trigger default enter key behaviour.